# C - algoritm - copy .txt to another .txt - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c

I wrote this code to copy text from one .txt file to another (also .txt).
my idea was to format the text to be 100 characters wide and count the lines to allocate a matrix[count_lines][100], copy the text to the matrix and pass it to the other .txt file.
however when I compile and run the code, Segmentation fault (core dumped) occurs.
would the error be in the code itself (functions, pointers, etc) or in my idea?
obs: I started studying programming recently, so if it's something I left out, I promise I'll study more hehe :).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CH_COL_MAX 100

int main(void){

    char **string, str_copy[CH_COL_MAX], letter1, letter2;
    int count_char = 0, count_lines = 0, size_col;

    FILE* fr;

    fr = fopen("main1.txt", "r+");

    if(fr == NULL){
        printf("\nData base error.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < CH_COL_MAX + 1; i++){   
            fscanf(fr, "%c", &letter1);
            count_char++;
                
            if(letter1 == '\n'){
                count_char = 0;
                i = 0;
            }
            
            if(count_char == 99){
                fprintf(fr, "\n");
                i = 0;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < CH_COL_MAX + 1; i++){ 
            fscanf(fr, "%c", &letter2);
                
            if(letter2 == '\n'){
                i = 0;
                count_lines++;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fr);

    string = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * count_lines);
    
    size_col = 100;

    for(int i = 0; i < count_lines; i++){
        string[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * size_col);
    }

    FILE* fc;

    fc = fopen("main1.txt", "r+");

    if(fc == NULL){
        printf("\nData base error.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < count_lines; i++){
            fscanf(fc, "%[^\n]s", string[i]);
        }
    }

    fclose(fc);

    FILE* fp;

    fp = fopen("main2.txt", "r+");

    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("\nData base error.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < count_lines; i++){
            fprintf(fp, "%s", string[i]);
            fprintf(fp, "\n");
        }   
    }

    fclose(fp);

    for(int i = 0; i < CH_COL_MAX; i++){
        free(string[i]);
    }

    free(string);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing to the same file you're reading from? C requires that you use `fflush()` or `fseek()` when you switch between reading and writing the same stream.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: Your loops that read from the file never check for EOF. How are they supposed to stop when they reach the end of the file?

Comment: Run your program in a debugger. At a minimum it will tell you the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault and that is critical data to have for your debugging.

Comment: Why do you need all this complication to copy from one file to another? Just call `fgets(line, sizeof line, file1); and `fputs(line, file2)`

Comment: Now it's working, I opened the two files and used fgets() and fputs() with feof(), besides it was much simpler, thanks for the help!